# Call retries were exceeded

Tags: next.js

I have a problem with my nextjs project that when I run npm run build I get this error

Knowing that when one of my friends tried my project on his laptop, he did not see any error

Error: Call retries were exceeded
at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (E:\Food-ordering\foor-ordering-app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\jest-worker\index.js:1:12037)
at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (E:\Food-ordering\foor-ordering-app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\jest-worker\index.js:1:12975)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:475:12)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
type: 'WorkerError'